# Sum of $\sum^\infty_{n=2} \frac{1}{\ln{(n!)}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am sorry that my question is not whether $\sum^\infty_{n=2} \frac{1}{\ln{(n!)}}$ convergent or not.

My question is how to compute the sum of series: 
$$\sum^\infty_{n=2} \frac{1}{\ln{(n!)}},$$
It is a question in a textbook, and I have worked on it for days, but fail.

Comment: @Dave : I don't know where to start with this

Comment: $\log(n!)\sim n\log n$, hence the given series is divergent by asymptotic comparison and Cauchy's condensation test. We have $$\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{1}{\log(n!)}\approx\log\log N.$$

Comment: Are you sure the question was to compute the sum, though? As @JackD'Aurizio's comment and my answer show, the series diverges to $+\infty$. Any professor asking you to compute the sum would be at best slightly sneaky.

Comment: Although the Question has been edited to make *convergence* rather than *evaluation* the central issue, the OP has done little else to suggest the problem has been "digested" before posting.  The *context* called for in putting the Question on-hold serves, among other purposes, to guide Readers as to what level of response will be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

We know that for $n\geq 2$: $n!\leq n^n$ clearly, because $n!=n(n-1)...(2)(1)$ while $n^n=(n)(n)...(n)(n)$. Since $\ln$ is an increasing function, we have $\ln(n!)\leq\ln(n^n)=n\ln(n)$. Hence,
$$\frac{1}{\ln(n!)}\geq\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$$
Can you determine whether $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$ diverges or not?

Comment: I am sorry that my question is not to show the convergence of it, my question is compute the sum of it. I am sorry for that.

Comment: @radium You should post a new question (since this is on hold) asking what you meant to, and be sure to include your attempts at a solution.

Comment: @radium The series *diverges to $\infty$*. The sum is $+\infty$. What else do you hope to get?

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be easy but disappointing to compute the sum: it's $\infty$. Indeed, you have a series of positive terms which diverges by comparison, since
$$
\ln n! = \sum_{k=1}^n \ln k \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} n\ln n
$$
and the (Bertrand) series $\sum_n \frac{1}{n\ln n}$ diverges. *(This last point e.g., by the series/integral comparison, as $\int_e^n \frac{dx}{x\ln x} = \ln\ln n$).*